# Alter statement in a Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I execute the code below:

```
use AdventureWorks2008R2
begin transaction
BEGIN
alter table HumanResources.Department add newcolumn int
update HumanResources.Department set newcolumn=1 where departmentid=1
END
commit
```

The error I get is:

> Invalid column name 'newcolumn'.

Can `ALTER` statements be included in Transactions like this? If so, how can I prevent this error?

I have researched this online [e.g. here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6f74a432-74df-41d8-aca4-0fd16a07d156/alter-table-statements-in-a-transaction).  I have not found an answer to my specific question.

Comment: Yes, you can. It is easy to check.

Comment: @Hamlet I think you may have missed the point of the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can include an `ALTER` in a transaction. The problem is that the parser validates the syntax for your `UPDATE` statement, and can't "see" that you are also performing an `ALTER`. One workaround is to use dynamic SQL, so that the parser doesn't inspect your syntax (and validate column names) until runtime, where the `ALTER` will have already happened:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  ALTER TABLE HumanResources.Department ADD newcolumn INT;

  EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE HumanResources.Department 
    SET newcolumn = 1 WHERE DepartmentID = 1;';

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Note that indentation makes code blocks much more easily identifiable (and your `BEGIN/END` was superfluous).

Comment: Is it possible to switch off parser validation? I guess not.

Comment: No, and how often are you adding columns to a table where this would be a problem? The above code could only be run once, for example. So using dynamic SQL for the ALTER too might make this a little more plausible.

Comment: I agree with what you have done +1.  The problem is that I have already written the script and will have to modify every SQL statement.  Are there any limitations to creating two transactions: one for the ALTER statements and one for the UPDATES/INSERTS.  Transaction one (ALTERS) would be committed before transaction two begins.

Comment: Transaction is completely irrelevant. Did you try splitting it out into two transactions? The parser still tries to validate the code in the second transaction before it starts executing anything - so the only way you'd be able to do it is to execute the first set of code exactly once, and after it is finished, attempt to run the second block of code. I understand you've already written code but you're going to have to change it somehow, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Aaron has explained everything already. Another alternative that works for ad-hoc scripts in SSMS is to insert the batch separator `GO` so that the script is sent as two parts to the server. This only works if it is valid to split the script in the first place (you can't split an `IF` body for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you check the existence of column, then it should work.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    IF COL_LENGTH('table_name', 'newcolumn') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE table_name ADD newcolumn INT;
    END

  EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE table_name
    SET newcolumn = 1 WHERE DepartmentID = 1;';

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: The `ALTER` isn't the part that fails.

Comment: I am sorry, but why would `UPDATE` fails if `ALTER` is working?

Comment: Because if you don't put the `UPDATE` in dynamic SQL, SQL Server tries to parse the column name mentioned in the `UPDATE` before it ever tries to alter the column. You took the code from my answer; didn't you read it, too?